# Supported Formats in ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I want to know which formats being supported in ArcGIS for Desktop? Vector, raster, DTED, XML and Web3D formats that I want to know. I researched a little but I couldn't find.

Examples for vector: MapInfo TAB, ASCI, VPF etc.

Examples for Raster: ADRG,RPF,VRML

Is there any documents that examines this issue?

Comment: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/datatypes/about-geographic-data-formats.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_4835793C55C0439593A46FD5BC9E64B9

Answer (score 2):

See here the [List of data formats supported in ArcGIS](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/datatypes/about-geographic-data-formats.htm).

For rasters, there is a more detailed list here: [List of supported raster and image data formats](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/raster-and-images/list-of-supported-raster-and-image-formats.htm)

And if you have the Data Interoperability extension, there's even more data formats supported, see [Supported formats with the Data Interoperability extension](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/data-interoperability/supported-formats-with-the-data-interoperability-extension.htm)

Comment: So can we say these formats are being supported in ArcGIS Server at the same time?

Comment: How do you intend to use them in ArcGIS Server? Data source for a map service, input/output of a GP service, ...?

Comment: oh sorry, these can be feature service, or they can be included by Gdb. Let's say if I share these raster formats as "share as a service" or they can be in a database and if I share that geodatabase.. What do you say?